# Arduino GET Method link

Tags: http, variables, url, arduino

I want to send two variables on method link arduino but my code only one variable

```
client.println("GET /input.php?id="+String(v1_dist_cm)+" HTTP/1.0");
```

how to send two variable at the same link

please i need answer

Answer (score 0):

You can delimt multiple vairables with the `&` character:

```
client.println("GET /input.php?id=" + String(v1_dist_cm) + "&anothervar=" + String(anotherVar) + " HTTP/1.0");
```